# Streaming iPlayer from MBP to AppleTV

Tags: appletv, airplay, hdmi

I'm thinking of getting an Apple TV and streaming BBC iPlayer to it via my 2009 MacBook Pro. So:

1. Is it possible?
2. What is the quality like on ATV content? Does it break up or buffer continuously or is it more or less like watching TV?
3. Another solution I am thinking of is to hook up the MacBook Pro to the TV without ATV but using an HDMI (?) cable. Is this going to be good quality? Is it a viable option? Worse than Airplay?

Comment: How do you get the HD TV quality stream from BBC iPlayer here in Spain.

Comment: It's a proxy but I don't think it's HD. I've only ever used it on my Mac not Tv.

Comment: Your original question had Spain edited out, but I would strongly recommend to test your source quality first (the connection to the BBC iPlayer, before spending too much time and money on the receiving end quality. You will need >1500kbps streaming speed to get good quality without huge buffering times. I do not know what Proxy are you using but it is better than anything I have!

Comment: Not sure why it edited out. I might go with Apple TV anyway as even with the absence of anything else it will be a sort of replacement for the missing channels. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Based on [an article in 2012](http://robskinner.net/2012/06/13/how-to-play-bbc-iplayer-on-apple-tv/), it should be possibile to AirPlay this easily.
2. The quality will either be 720P or 1080P, buffering based on the quality of your internet connection. If your connection is fast you have no problems as long as your stream can handle it ;)
3. Yes you can do this too, a cable is a direct connection not using Apple TV. It's cheaper as you don't have to buy an Apple TV. However, with Apple TV you can do much more - and it will show subtitles for example in a pre-chosen style.

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess the ATV re Cable question is one of quality. We do rent/buy a bit of stuff from iTunes so would this be better quality via the ATV than from the computer and streaming?

Comment: Streamed content from iTunes has a couple of choices, you can either stream direct from the AppleTV straight from the internet, or if the item is in your iTunes library on your Mac, it can stream it direct from there using home sharing.  Neither approach requires AirPlay.  Airplay would only be required for streams and files not located in your iTunes library either local or in the cloud.  Direct streaming of iTunes content is likely to be the same as playing straight from your mac.  Airplay can introduce lesser quality, depends on your wireles setup.